# Calculate mean of respective column values based on condition

Tags: r

I have a data.frame named `sampleframe` where I have stored all the table values. Inside `sampleframe` I have columns `id`, `month`, `sold`.

```
 id month   SMarch  SJanFeb churn
 101    1   0.00    0.00    1
 101    2   0.00    0.00    1
 101    3   0.00    0.00    1
 108    2   0.00    6.00    1
 103    2   0.00    10.00   1
 160    1   0.00    2.00    1
 160    2   0.00    3.00    1
 160    3   0.50    0.00    0
 164    1   0.00    3.00    1
 164    2   0.00    6.00    1
```

I would like to calculate average sold for last three months based on `ID`. If it is month 3 then it has to consider average sold for the last two months based on ID, if it is month 2 then it has to consider average sold for 1 month based on ID., respectively for all months.

I have used `ifelse` and `mean` function to avail it but some rows are missing when i try to use it for all months

Query that I have used for execution

```
sampleframe$Churn <- ifelse(sampleframe$Month==4|sampleframe$Month==5|sampleframe$Month==6, ifelse(sampleframe$Sold<0.7*mean(sampleframe$Sold[sampleframe$ID[sampleframe$Month==-1&sampleframe$Month==-2&sampleframe$Month==-3]]),1,0),0)
```

adding according to the logic of the query it should compare with the previous months sold value of 70% and if the current value is higher than previous average months values then it should return 1 else 0

Comment: Please learn how to [format your question text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Hi Jaap, thank you for suggestion, but table values how to display

Comment: Can you update with the expected output.

Comment: @akrun ouput it should display 0 or 1 based on the sold value

Comment: @Pallavi It would be very helpful if you can also update with the expected output so that we can crosscheck the results.

Comment: @akrun please check edited table for reference am able to get it using mysql workbench but using R am not able. No in that i SMar and SJanFeb values are for your reference but Churn is what am expected the column as u have used soldAvg column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear about the expected output.  Based on the description about calculating average 'sold' for each 3 months, grouped by 'id', we can use `roll_mean` from `library(RcppRoll)`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'id', `if` the number of rows is greater than 1, we get the `roll_mean` with `n` specified as 3 and concatenate with the averages for less than 3 or `else` i.e. for 1 observation, get the value itself.

```
library(RcppRoll)
library(data.table)
k <- 3
setDT(df1)[, soldAvg := if(.N>1) c(cumsum(sold[1:(k-1)])/1:(k-1), 
      roll_mean(sold,n=k, align='right')) else as.numeric(sold), id]

df1
 #     id month sold  soldAvg
 #1: 101     1  124 124.0000
 #2: 101     2  211 167.5000
 #3: 104     3  332 332.0000
 #4: 105     4  124 124.0000
 #5: 101     5  211 182.0000
 #6: 101     6  332 251.3333
 #7: 101     7  124 222.3333
 #8: 101     8  211 222.3333
 #9: 101     9  332 222.3333
#10: 102    10  124 124.0000
#11: 102    12  211 167.5000
#12: 104     3  332 332.0000
#13: 105     4  124 124.0000
#14: 102     5  211 182.0000
#15: 102     6  332 251.3333
#16: 106     7  124 124.0000
#17: 107     8  211 211.0000
#18: 102     9  332 291.6667
#19: 103    11  124 124.0000
#20: 103     2  211 167.5000
#21: 108     3  332 332.0000
#22: 108     4  124 228.0000
#23: 109     5  211 211.0000
#24: 103     6  332 222.3333
#25: 104     7  124 262.6667
#26: 105     8  211 153.0000
#27: 103    10  332 291.6667
```

Comment: After installing library files when i try to execute the above statement in R studio it is showing "could not find function roll_mean"

Comment: @Pallavi It is in `RcppRoll`.  Have you installed it?

Comment: i have installed it :)

Comment: @Pallavi Have you called `library(RcppRoll)` before running the code.  The binary part is not clear to me.

Comment: yes after adding library(RcppRoll) am able to execute the code. here in the code what is "n" signifies

Comment: @Pallavi It signifies the window size

Comment: To explain about binary part when the sales month==3 then it has to calculate average sold values of last two months i.e.,2,1 and compare it with month 3 quantity sold. if quantity sold of march month is less than or equal to .7% of feb and jan month values then it should return 1 else false. if condition is true 1 else 0

Comment: @Pallavi I noticed that some months are missing for IDs.  What to do in that case?

Comment: it should work based on unique ID thats it if months are not there then consider it as NA

Comment: @Pallavi Just had my lunch.  Let me look into it.  But, as I mentioned, if you have provided an expected output, it makes it more easier.

Comment: @Pallavi If we look at the first id i.e. 101, there is month 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.  What will be the corresponding value for the average?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for above Question can be done by using library(dplyr) and use this query to avail the output

```
resultData <- group_by(data, KId) %>% 
    arrange(sales_month) %>% 
    mutate(monthMinus1Qty = lag(quantity_sold,1), monthMinus2Qty = lag(quantity_sold, 2)) %>% 
    group_by(KId, sales_month) %>%
    mutate(previous2MonthsQty = sum(monthMinus1Qty, monthMinus2Qty, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%  
    mutate(result = ifelse(quantity_sold/previous2MonthsQty >= 0.6,0,1)) %>%
    select(KId,sales_month, quantity_sold, result)
```

link to refer for solution and output [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538425/find-a-function-to-return-value-based-on-condition-using-r)