# Find a function to return value based on condition using R

Tags: r

I have a table with values

```
KId sales_month quantity_sold
100        1    0
100        2    0
100        3    0
496        2    6
511        2    10
846        1    4
846        2    6
846        3    1
338        1    6
338        2    0
```

now i require output as

```
KId sales_month quantity_sold result
100           1     0         1
100           2     0         1
100           3     0         1
496           2     6         1
511           2     10        1
846           1     4         1
846           2     6         1
846           3     1         0
338           1     6         1
338           2     0         1
```

Here, the calculation has to go as such if quantity sold for the month of march(3) is less than **60%** of  two months January(1) and  February(2) quantity sold then the result should be **1** or else it should display **0**. Require solution to perform this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made any attempts at this problem yourself?

Comment: @ZDavies i have done it by using Mysql queries it worked fine by using sub-query with case statement but similar when am trying to do it by using ifelse for dataframe it is going vain with loss of records and with wrong output.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far... also your question is unclear... what do you mean by 60% of two months January(1) and February(2)... there are multiple 1s and 2s in you data...

Comment: @Gaurav, using sampleBubble$result<-ifelse(sampleBubble$Sales_Month==4|sampleBubble$Sales_Month==5|sampleBubble$Sales_Month==6,ifelse(sampleBubble$Quantity_Sold<0.6*mean(sampleBubble$Quantity_Sold[sampleBubble$KId[sampleBubble$Sales_Month==-1&sampleBubble$Sales_Month==-2&sampleBubble$Sales_Month==-3]]),1,0),0) which is resulting "NA". Here sampleBubble is the data.frame

Comment: You cannot include the part `mean(sample‌​Bubble$Quantity_Sold[sampleBubble$KId[sampleBubble$Sales_Month==-1&sampleBubble$S‌​ales_Month==-2&sampleBubble$Sales_Month==-3]])` inside your `ifelse` statement... `ifelse` statement can only check the values of a particular row against a value in that same row or a previously defined variable with absolute value... if you derive a value from all rows of a ceratain dataframe inside the ifelse statement acting on a row of that same dataframe its gonna throw NA...

Comment: @Gaurav thank you for suggestion but would like to know which function will better suite at this point of time to retrieve expected output.

Comment: do `value <- 0.6*mean(whatever)` and then once you have that do you `ifelse` statement with your condition of `sampleBubble$Quantity_Sold < value`... you can break down you code into steps... no need to do it all in one go

Comment: Gaurav i tried in this way "meanQS<-0.7*mean(sampleBubble$Quantity_Sold)" then i used "sampleBubble$Churnval<-ifelse(sampleBubble$Sales_Month==4|sampleBubble$Sales_Month==5|sampleBubble$Sales_Month==6,ifelse(sampleBubble$Quantity_Sold<with(sampleBubble,subset(Quantity_Sold,Sales_Month==4|Sales_Month==5|Sales_Month==6)),1,0),0)" it resulted 0

Comment: for all the records in Churnval but when i apply like "sampleBubble$Churnval<-ifelse(sampleBubble$Sales_Month==4|sampleBubble$Sales_Month==5|sampleBubble$Sales_Month==6,ifelse(sampleBubble$Quantity_Sold<meanQS[with(sampleBubble,subset(Quantity_Sold,Sales_Month==4|Sales_Month==5|Sales_Month==6))],1,0),0)" then am getting Error in meanQS[with(sampleBubble, subset(Quantity_Sold, Sales_Month ==  : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, your requirement is to compare sold quantity in month t with the sum of quantity sold in months t-1 and t-2. If so, I can suggest using dplyr package that offer the nice feature of grouping rows and mutating columns in your data frame.

```
resultData <- group_by(data, KId) %>% 
    arrange(sales_month) %>% 
    mutate(monthMinus1Qty = lag(quantity_sold,1), monthMinus2Qty = lag(quantity_sold, 2)) %>% 
    group_by(KId, sales_month) %>%
    mutate(previous2MonthsQty = sum(monthMinus1Qty, monthMinus2Qty, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%  
    mutate(result = ifelse(quantity_sold/previous2MonthsQty >= 0.6,0,1)) %>%
    select(KId,sales_month, quantity_sold, result)
```

The result is as below:
[image: example of data frame processed by the above code]

Adding

```
select(KId,sales_month, quantity_sold, result)
```

at the end let us display only columns we care about (and not all these intermediate steps).

I believe this should satisfy your requirement. NA is the result column are due to 0/0 division or no data at all for the previous months.
Should you need to expand your calculation beyond one calendar year, you can add year column and adjust group_by() arguments appropriately.
For more information on dplyr package, follow [this link](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)

Comment: Hi, this helped me to retrieve data to which am expecting but how can i hide those mutate columns which are used in data.frame

Comment: Hi am able to do hide those columns by using subset() but how to remove those NA to be replaced with 0 to show exact output as shown above

Comment: I edited the answer to show another solution on how to display only relevant columns. To replace NAs you can just use resultData$result[is.na(resultData$result)]<-0